# Illegal string offset 'date'

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, simplexml

I am trying to upgrade a friend's Wordpress site to the latest versions of Wordpress and PHP.
All is working fine except for a scrolling news ticker he uses on his homepage that errors out with "Illegal string offset 'date'", and no news is shown. 
This is the script:

```
<?php
$xmlOption = get_option('xmlFeed');
if (!isset($xmlOption)) {
    $buildURL = "https://wordpress.org/news/feed/";
    $request  = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_URL, $buildURL);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($request);
    curl_close($request);
    $xml     = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
    $channel = $xml->channel;
    delete_option('xmlFeed');
    $otion = array(
        'xml' => $channel,
        'date' => date('y-m-d')
    );
    add_option('xmlFeed', $option);
}
if ($xmlOption['date'] == date('y-m-d')) {
    $channel = $xmlOption['xml'];
} else {
    $buildURL = "https://wordpress.org/news/feed/";
    $request  = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_URL, $buildURL);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($request);
    curl_close($request);
    $xml     = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
    $channel = $xml->channel;
    delete_option('xmlFeed');
    $otion = array(
        'xml' => $channel,
        'date' => date('y-m-d')
    );
    add_option('xmlFeed', $option);
}
$i = 0;
while ($i <= 5) {
    echo "<li><a href='" . $channel->item->$i->link . "' target='_blank'>" . $channel->item->$i->title . "</a></li>";
    $i++;
}
?>
```

I noticed the use of $otion two times, which i thought was maybe a typo. But when i changed that to $option the rest of the page was not parsed, so I guess that isn't the problem.

As I am not a coder and i pulled my hairs out for 2 nights now.
Time to get some help before i have none left.
Anyone can help me with this one?

Comment: My initial guess is that `$otion` *is* a typo, and should be `$option` (even though it halts the page). Otherwise, where would the following line get its `$option` array from: `add_option('xmlFeed', $option);` So fix the typo (because you must), and check your error logs/turn on error reporting thereafter to see what error is then being spit out.

Comment: So my guts were right about the $otion. I changed the code and the error i can find in the logs is: `'PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed'`
I'll Google on that in the meanwhile

Comment: "*I'll Google on that in the meanwhile*" Why bother when typically the first 5 results in Google bring you right back to StackOverflow? Just use the search tool here ;) Saves you a round trip.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a real answer to my question, but I found [another script](http://bavotasan.com/2010/display-rss-feed-with-php/) that, with some small changes, works perfectly. So I'm happy.

`<?php
        $rss = new DOMDocument();
        $rss->load('http://wordpress.org/news/feed/');
        $feed = array();
        foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
            $item = array ( 
                'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                );
            array_push($feed, $item);
        }
        $limit = 5;
        for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
            $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
            $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
            echo '<li><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'" target="_blank">'.$title.'</a></li>';
        }
    ?>`

It is smaller and cleaner.
Thanks for your help @Marcus